# I can't get Ubuntu Studio 22.04 to open from a live USB pen drive

Tags: live-usb, ubuntu-studio, 22.04, busybox

I have made two live USB pen drives. Using two different computers, both running Ubuntu FF. I downloaded the iso from a torrent. I check summed the file. I formatted the USB key to FAT 32, created the live image using Unetbootin, and keep getting a long busybox error message. I make a Kubuntu live USB the same way any it's fine. I copied this text from a picture of the error message:

*0.098110] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS*

*0.880932] integrity: Couldn't parse dbx signatures: -74
[
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.) Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
losetup: /cdrom/casper/filesystem. squashfs: Warning: file does not fit into a 512-byte sector; th mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /filesystem.squashfs failed: Invalid argument Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on /filesystem.squashfs*

There may be a little bit of the message missing on the longer lines...

Comment: UNetbootin has also not been working for me with Ubuntu newer than about 12.04. I'm not sure if it is still maintained. For Windows I recommend Rufus and Etcher. For Linux I recommend mkusb, Startup Disk Creator and Gnome Disks. Ventoy also deserves mention.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, did you actually shutdown Windows? Use `dd` to create a USB installer, it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem.
I fixed it by formatting the usb key to ext4 (right now posting from Ubuntu Studio 22.04 Live !).
The problem is that the filesystem.squashfs file is 4.3Gb which is more than what a FAT32 can hold (4G max per file).
I guess that you can also format it as NTFS and it will work the same way I got with ext4.

Hope it helps

Comment: I am trying with NTFS bootable USB drive, but it is not at all booting !