# UbuntuStudio 22.04 initramfs error in USB FAT32 live session

Tags: system-installation, ntfs, ext4, initramfs, fat32

I am trying to install UbuntuStudio 22.04 in my machine. The problem is that the image file that needs to be copied into the USB stick is 4.2 GBs. This appears to be causing the initramfs problem as the USB stick is set to FAT32 format. I have found a 6 month old post with a similar problem here [I can't get Ubuntu Studio 22.04 to open from a live USB pen drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404967/i-cant-get-ubuntu-studio-22-04-to-open-from-a-live-usb-pen-drive). It suggests using EXT4 or NTFS for the USB drive to solve this problem, however if I use EXT4 then I cannot create the bootable USB, and if I use NTFS then my computer does not recognize the USB on BOOT.

How can one solve this? If I cannot get that image in a usable/bootable USB stick there is no way to install the OS.

can someone please help.

thank you

Comment: All ISOs are QA tested & successfully write using the methods Ubuntu (and all *flavors*) document how to write an ISO to media for install.  That is done for all releases/flavors & often using the *daily* ISOs so problems can be detected when change(s) are made.  Just write the ISO using the official Ubuntu methods and you won't have issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to burn an ISO file to a USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398432/how-to-burn-an-iso-file-to-a-usb)

Comment: Does your computer boot using UEFI or Legacy?

Answer (score 0):

I have just now, tested creating a bootable USB stick with MX Live USB-Maker that formats the USB with ISO9660 and can fit that image and keep the bootable aspect of the USB.

Answer (score 0):

### Make Bootable USB by Hand (UEFI only)

Most modern computers, (UEFI), do not need a Live USB maker to boot Ubuntu, (or Windows).

In Ubuntu use GParted to create an ~8GB NTFS partition on the USB or on the Target drive. (In Windows use Disk Management).

In Ubuntu use Archive Manager, (or 7Zip), to extract the ISO file to the NTFS partition.

When booting use the applicable F key to open the UEFI menu and then select the USB or NTFS partition to boot.